# How to get a unique array from an object via new set?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to get a unique array from an object via new set?

I have an array with objects, how can I get a unique array, but only so that the id is preserved?

I.e: `[{id: 1, title: 'test1'}, {id: 2, title: 'test2'}]`

```
const arr = [{id: 1, title: 'test1'}, {id: 2, title: 'test2'}, {id: 1: title: 'test1'}]
const filtered = arr.filter((item) => item.title)
const result = Array.from(new set(arr))
```

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. You say "only so that the id is preserved" I'm not sure you only want the id, as in id:1 because your "i.e." shows multiple properties. Do you mean so that only distinct objects are left? set should have a capital as in Set.

Comment: This appears to be two questions. Remove all attributes from the objects in the array other than id, and then remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a hash table and get the values of it.

This approach takes the **last** found object with the same `id`.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 1, title: 'first' }, { id: 2, title: 'test2' }, { id: 1, title: 'last' }],
    unique = Object.values(array.reduce((r, o) => (r[o.id] = o, r), {}));

console.log(unique);
```

By using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with a closure, you could filter the array.

This approach takes the **first** found object with the same `id`.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 1, title: 'first' }, { id: 2, title: 'test2' }, { id: 1, title: 'last' }],
    unique = array.filter((s => ({ id }) => !s.has(id) && s.add(id))(new Set));

console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a set, a Map might be better, just create a map with the id as the key.

eg.

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, title: 'test1'}, {id: 2, title: 'test2'}, {id: 1, title: 'test1'}];

const d = new Map(arr.map(m => [m.id, m]));

console.log([...d.values()]);
```